# Converting PHP method into Java Code

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Currently Im converting this code to a java programming language. This code checks if the sentence contains the key phrase

example:

> ```
>    sentence = "Hello world. Programming for every one"
>     key phrase = "helo wrld"
> ```

this will return true

```
function containsKeyPhrase($phrase,$key_phrase){
        $min_words = 1; 
        $key = preg_split("/[' ]/", strtolower($key_phrase));  
        $max_words = count($key);  
        $ngrams = array(); 
        $words  = str_word_count(strtolower($phrase), 1);

        print_r(array_slice($words, 1, 1));

        $word_count = count($words);  
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $word_count - $min_words; $i++) {
            for ($j = $min_words; $j <= $max_words && ($j + $i) <= $word_count; $j++) { 
                $ngrams[] = implode(' ',array_slice($words, $i, $j));
            }
        }

        $n_grams = array_unique($ngrams);

        print_r($n_grams);

        foreach ($n_grams as $ngram) {  
            if (levenshtein( strtolower ($key_phrase),  strtolower ($ngram)) < 5 && soundex( strtolower ($key_phrase))== soundex( strtolower ($ngram))) {
                return true; 
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

I have created a java version of it. But the problem is I keep getting an error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I have tested all the function  and its running fine. Also is there any array_unique, levenshtein and soundex version in java that i can use?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        containsKeyPhrase("Hello World","hello");
    }

    private static boolean containsKeyPhrase(String msg, String key_phrase) { 
            String[] tokens = key_phrase.toLowerCase().split("[\\s']");
            String[] words = msg.toLowerCase().split("[\\s']");
            ArrayList<String> nGrams = new ArrayList<String>();
            int min_words = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= words.length - min_words; i++) {
                for (int j = min_words; j <= tokens.length
                        && (j + i) <= words.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(implode(" ",stringArraySlice(words, i, j)));
                }
            }

            HashSet hs = new HashSet();
            hs.addAll(nGrams);
            nGrams.clear();
            nGrams.addAll(hs); 

        //Still Implementing    
        // $n_grams = array_unique($ngrams);
        //
        // print_r($n_grams);
        //
        // foreach ($n_grams as $ngram) {
        // if (levenshtein( strtolower ($key_phrase), strtolower ($ngram)) < 5
        // && soundex( strtolower ($key_phrase))== soundex( strtolower
        // ($ngram))) {
        // return true;
        // }
        // }

        return false;

    }

    private static String implode(String separator, String... data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("lenght:" + data.length);
    if (data.length > 0) {
        for (String str : data) { 
            sb.append(str);
            sb.append(separator);
        }  
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
    public static String[] stringArraySlice(String[] array, int offset,
        int lenght) {
    List<String> newArr = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        if (offset > array.length - 1) {
            break;
        }
        newArr.add(array[offset++]);
    }

    String[] arrs = (String[]) newArr.toArray(new String[newArr.size()]);
    return arrs;
}
}
```

Comment: in the example keyphrase is it "hello wrld" or "hello world" ? also is case significant in a match or not?

Comment: Your for loops seem to go one too far. Indexes go from 0 to *length-1*

Comment: @Mukul Goel yes its "hello wrld". levenshtein function handles that to match it. also it ignores case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to implement `stringArraySlice`. You can use [Array.copyofRange()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29).

Having said that, you have an error:

```
for (int i = offset; i < array.length && i <= lenght; i++) {
```

If `offset`is 3 and `length` is 2 e.g., then you would get an empty array, because `i <= length` is `true` before the loop starts. And if the array is empty, then you have a problem in your `implode` method:

```
sb.append(data[data.length - 1]);
```

which would be equal to

```
sb.append(data[-1]);
```

Comment: Arrays.copyOfRange(words,1, 1) has different output with array_slice(words,1, 1)

Comment: When the array words sets to  [0] hello, [1] world. Using `Arrays.copyOfRange(words,1, 1)` outputs nothing but  `array_slice(words,1, 1)` outputs world

Comment: @Snippet The equivalent of `array_slice(words,1, 1)` is `Arrays.copyOfRange(words,1, 2)`. The last parameter is the exclusive end index. So you use `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start index, start index + length)`.